# UIWebView not working first time in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, ios9

I have a `UIWebView`, whose delegate is set in `viewDidLoad` and then a URL is passed to it. This screen is loaded once the app launches. The `webview`doesn't load the URL and the delegate method (given below) is not called

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

There is a `button` on the same screen. When i press that after app launches. The same Web view loads.

Please tell me why my UIWebview is not loading for the first time?

It happens only in iOS 9. In iOS 8, it works perfectly.

Comment: Do you load the same URL in both cases? What URL are you trying to load?

Answer (score 0):

Add below key in you `.plist` and try.

[image]

Comment: same problem here, any solutions?